# onstructor Sort(String[][], 11, 12);" is undefined in junit

Tags: java, junit4

I'm trying to write a test for the following method:

```
 public class Sort {

...
...
...

    public static String[][] findRanks(String[][] array, int indexOfPoints, int indexOfRank) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { 
            int compare = 1;
            if (i < array.length - 2)
                compare = Double.valueOf(array[i][indexOfPoints]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(array[i + 1][indexOfPoints]));

            if (i == array.length - 1 || compare != 0) { 
                array[i][indexOfRank] = Integer.toString(i + 1);
            }
            else {
                array[i][indexOfRank] = Integer.toString(i + 1) + " - " + Integer.toString(i + 2);
                array[i+1][indexOfRank] = Integer.toString(i + 1) + " - " + Integer.toString(i + 2);
                i++;
            }
        }
        return array;   
    }

}
```

I've tryed the following test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SortTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testFindRanks() {
        String[][] array = { {"Siim Susi","12.61","5.00","9.22","1.50","60.39","16.43","21.60","2.60","35.81","5.25.72","6253.0","1"}, 
                {"Beata Kana","13.04","4.53","7.79","1.55","64.72","18.74","24.20","2.40","28.20","6.50.76","5290.0","2"}};

        Sort test1 = new Sort(array, 11, 12); //This is where the problem is

        String[][] expected = { {"Siim Susi","12.61","5.00","9.22","1.50","60.39","16.43","21.60","2.60","35.81","5.25.72","6253.0","1"}, 
                                {"Beata Kana","13.04","4.53","7.79","1.55","64.72","18.74","24.20","2.40","28.20","6.50.76","5290.0","2"}};

        assertTrue(expected.equals(test1));
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

But the test keeps telling me "the constructor Sort(String[][], 11, 12);" is undefined.
Why does it think it has to be a constructor and how do i fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write

```
    String[][] results = Sort.findRanks(array, 11, 12);
```

and to make your unit tests cleaner, more idiomatic and easier to maintain, you could also refactor it a bit:

```
public class SortTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testFindRanks() {
        String[][] array = {...};
        String[][] expected = {...};

        String[][] result = Sort.findRanks(array, 11, 12);

        assertArrayEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

That is, separate the test setup, the call to the tested method, and the verification code. Also remove the `fail` call from the end, as it will make your test always fail :-)

Comment: @Sean, @nicholas, oops, fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do

```
 String[][] actual = Sort.findRanks(array, 11, 12);
```

and then

```
assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```

Comment: findRanks(...) is static, and although this will work, it is not the preferred syntax.

Comment: @nicholas I did notice it after I answered and I have revised my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor call:

```
new Sort(array, 11, 12)
```

And the compiler complains if no such constructor is available

Read [about Constructors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) in the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)

Answer (score 1):

The message is exactly correct: Your `Sort` class doesn't define a constructor that takes `String[][], int, int` as parameters, which you are calling on the line that has the problem.

You need:

```
String[][] actual = Sort.findRanks(array, 11, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not look like you have a `Sort` constructor defined (at least in the code you posted).  And the compiler/IDE is telling you that you do not have a `Sort` constructor defined.

You probably mean to be calling this line:

```
String[][] value = Sort.findRanks(array, 11, 12);
//Sort test1 = new Sort(array, 11, 12); <-- dont call this...call the above...
```